# EF Core: Where Vs FirstOrDefaultAsync

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

Is it right to assume that **FirstOrDefaultAsync** runs on the client (web server) side and **Where** runs on host (SQL server) side, thus using **Where** is much better than using **FirstOrDefaultAsync**?

If the answer is yes, then how can I leverage the power of **async** since I can't call **FirstOrDefaultAsync** after **Where**?

How can **await** in this case to use & optimize my recourses to the best extent?

Comment: Seems that you're confusing *client* execution and *forced* execution. It would be very bad news if `FirstOrDefault(Async)` would run on the client. And you certainly can  run FirstOrDefaultAsync after Where.

Answer (score 5):

Two different things here

- `Where` defines filter which will be used later for generating SQL
  and do not execute query.
- `FirstOrDefaultAsync` defines filter and **executes** query on the SQL Server

So all of your assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: The distinction between filter and filter/execute LINQ methods in EF cleared up my misunderstanding. Thank you. I wish EF made the summary documentation clearer on this instead of generic linq documentation.

Answer (score 3):

"I can't call FirstOrDefaultAsync after Where?"

```
var result = await context.Entities
    .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => /* some condition */);
```

equals...

```
var result = await context.Entities
    .Where(x => /* some condition */)
    .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Why use `Where` over the expression right in the `FirstOrDefault`? Reasons include:

- Readability / Organization.
- Conditional query composition.

An example of conditional composition: If you have a startDate parameter that is optional that you want to check and filter on if present:

Embedded parameter check:

```
var result = await context.Entities
    .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => !startDate.HasValue || x.StartDate >= startDate.Value);
```

Conditional composition:

```
var query = context.Entities.AsQueryable();
if(startDate.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.StartDate >= startDate.Value);

var results = await query
    .OrderBy(x => x.StartDate)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

When you start adding several optional conditions, the embedded conditional checks can get rather messy to read and error prone with the risk of mismatching parenthesis "()" between all of the `&&` and `||` conditions. It ultimately means more work for EF and the resulting SQL to sift through. Conditional composition only adds the filtering expression if it is needed, resulting in simpler, faster queries when the conditions aren't used.

Key points to consider:

- Only use `First*` methods with an `OrderBy*` clause to ensure they are repeatable.
- Only use `*OrDefault` methods where you explicitly expect no result or a default value. Otherwise use `First`/`Single` etc. and handle the exception.
- Don't fall into the trap believing that `async` makes queries faster and should be used by default. It actually makes queries slightly slower. (Due to context switching)

`async` is about making things like web requests more responsive during particularly expensive operations. If something is going to take, say, more than 500ms to run, `async` can help ensure the web server request threads are responding to new requests while that is running. If every request is delegating to a worker thread with awaited resumption points, what should be "in & out" quick hits end up taking longer on average, and messier to debug. It can also be used in situations where a particular operation will be called quite frequently by a lot of potential requests, though in that case it is firstly important to ensure it's running on hardware scaled for that amount of traffic.